# NHibernate: Maintaining foreign-key relationship with collections while minimizing data transfer

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-web-api

I have a classic parent-collection of children relationship that is being used in a web solution.

I want to be able to persist the children individually, but I also want to avoid being redundant.  It seems everyone says the child should be defined as follows:

```
public class Child {
   public virtual int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual string Name {get; set;}
   public virtual Parent {get; set;}
}
```

With that, I could ensure that the child has a reference to its parent.

The thing is, when pulling these Child objects from the application, I don't want a copy of the Parent being loaded with each of the children in the collection.

It might be useful to know that I'm using JSON.net to serialize.

Again, my goal here is to be able to persist children individually, but not to have to store the entire Parent object inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to go is just use a DTO/view model. Use a mapper to transfer from your entities to this lighter weight class, and return the lighter class. I resisted this approach for a while, insisting that creating DTO/view model classes was just doubling my effort, but ultimately that is the most productive methodology that is least likely to bite you in the rear later.

That being said, you could decorate `Parent` with `JsonIgnoreAttribute`, but A) that muddles presentation or perhaps business concerns with your domain and B) it's just laying off the inevitable.

Comment: I'll accept this as the solution.  JsonIgnoreAttribute isn't going to cut it here unfortunately.  I thought of this a few days ago, but was trying to get around it.  If it's what people are doing to get around the problem though, I'll just have to bite the bullet.

Answer (score 0):

If you load the children in 1 session, NHibernate will only create 1 instance of each unique parent in the database - even to the point that if a parent is one of the children you've loaded, it won't go and load it again or create a new object.  This is basically the "object identity" that NHibernate maintains - within a session, NHibernate will only create 1 instance  of an entity for a row (there are a few exceptions where you can make it do otherwise, but typically this will hold true).

Comment: I'm not worried about the time spent querying the database.  The problem for me is that when I go to serialize, JSON.NET WILL duplicate that data, writing it out for each child.

Comment: Then the issue isn't really related to NHibernate but rather to how to get JSON.NET to either maintain object references (see http://johnnycode.com/2012/04/10/serializing-circular-references-with-json-net-and-entity-framework/) or to tell JSON.NET to ignore the Parent property